# Обработка большого объема данных построчно PHP

Tags: php, json

Возникла проблема с обработкой большого объема данных построчно (файлы более 300мб). В определенный момент работа просто останавливается (даже не появляется ошибки 500 или иной другой). При этом всем работа заканчивается на случайной строке, выдавая на выходе разный объем данных в конечном файле.

Пример кода:

```
$file = 'file.json'; //Читаемый файл
$new_file = 'new_file.json'; //Новый файл
$json = fopen($file,'r'); 
file_put_contents($new_file, ''); //Очищаем новый файл, если там были какие-либо данные.
$i=0;
$ids = array();

while(!feof($json)){
  $line = fgets($json);
  $new_line = rtrim($line, ",\n");
  if(strlen($new_line)>42){
    $obj = json_decode($new_line,true);
    //Имя ячейки данных
    if(!is_null($obj['properties']['Код'])) {
      $name = stripslashes($obj['properties']['Название']);
      $key = $name.' '.$obj['properties']['Код']." ";
      if (in_array($obj['properties']['Код'] ,$ids)){
        $key = $key."(".$i.")";
      }
      array_push($ids, $obj['properties']['Код']);
    } else {
      $key = $i;
    }
    //Новая строка как именованный массив
    $obj2[$key] = [
      "Название" => $name,
      "Код" => $obj['properties']['Код'],
      "geometry" => $obj['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
    ];
    $new_line = json_encode($obj2,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES).","; //приводим строку в нужный вид
    file_put_contents($new_file, $new_line.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND); //Записываем строку в конец нового файла
    $i++;
    $obj2 = []; //очистка до нового цикла
  }
}

fclose($file);
```

Прописывал в конфиги, но результата не дало:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('max_input_time',-1);
```

Comment: перепишите скрипт так, что бы его можно было запускать с командной строки и скорее всего ошибка быстро себя проявит.

Comment: На данный момент доступа к машине нет. Только к ftp и самому сайту.

Comment: Может попробовать использовать генератор?

Comment: У вас скорее всего виртуальный хостинг и провайдер режет вас по времени выполнения или по времени занятия ресурсов без всяких ошибок. Грузить хостинг на дешевых тарифах вам не позволят.

Answer (score 0):

Может это поможет
Открываем искомый файл

```
 $f=fopen ($filename, 'r');
    while (!feof ($f)) {
// Читаем килобайтный блок, отдаем его в вывод и сбрасываем в буфер
      echo fread ($f, 1024);
      flush ();
    }
```

Comment: При использовании такой структуры json_decode почему-то перестает нормально работать и все последующие манипуляции выдают null значения `"1":{"Название":null,"Код":null,"geometry":null}`     P.S. Аналогично и при увеличении буфера до 8192

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/345024/ глянь тут

Answer (score 0):

Вы упираетесь в ограничения памяти, выделенной для работы PHP.
Вам может помочь
    ini_set('memory_limit','512M');

Цифра подбирается экспериментально.